# Which Protocol is Recommended For Sending GPS Datas From Android Application To The Server

Tags: android, protocols

I am beginner in android programming. I am working on sending data( GPS datas ) from android application to  the server nowadays. But I don't know which protocol is better for this subject.

What are the recommended sources for me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a HTTP/S [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) server to receive the data.

As far and the data format I would use either [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

JSON is generally simpler and more lightweight than XML, and if you don't need the extra features of XML JSON is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. I will take into consideration your answer.